# Java regex matcher fails to work

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

Hello i have regex problem, my code is suposed to check a lot xml files and changes some places words. all is going ok till i use matches.replaceAll

i have looked into google and cant find solution.
So code read each file line by line and check if in it something matches from pattern .

```
String patternStringDepOne = "(\\=(Dep)|\\=(Dep_LS)|(Dep)|(Dep_LS))((\\.dbo\\.)|\\.\\[dbo\\])";
```

There are multiple patterns, and each must be checked.

so code for checking

```
while(matcherDep.find()) { 
    if (matcherDep.group(2) != null) {
         if (matcherDep.group(2).matches("Dep") || matcherDep.group(2).matches("Dep_LS")) {
              String replaceAllDep = matcherDep.replaceAll(" <DEP>$6");
         }
    }
}
```

so this par check for total of 4 groups 2,3,4,5 and change match with word.
My problem is that after a lot matches it gives me error, and i have no idea why, why its working before and after it doesn't work. if i comment out  line with replace all it works. Error goes from one line to next depending how much replacing it does.

Error is:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
>     at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536)
> ```

Also since in one while statement there are one if statement like in code for each group.  and it usually fails at last if statement. But if i Write    *System.out.println*    just after    *While*    statement before if statements it prints out for one group founded match for rest null;

So any idea why its happening and how to fix it would be nice.

So in other words, i have about 680 xml files, in them in need to search for

> Dep , [Dep] , Dep_LS  and  [Dep_LS]

And two other variables in similar configuration
in all kinds possitions, *Dep* can be first word can be in middle of text, can be one can be multiple of them. I need to change them to  for all four *Dep* variants. One xml file looks like this

> Dep.dbo.ISINsdjndfadsfasd adsf.dsafadsf asd()dfasd Dep.dbo.jodnsf.sdfj
>   afsdasf adfa.sda.asdf asfd () das INNER JOIN Dep.dbo.ISIN_CALCULATED
>   ISIN_FACT ON (Dep.dbo.ISIN.ISIN_ID=[Dep].dbo.EVENT.EVENT_ISSUER) INNER
>   Dep.[dbo].ISINsdjndfadsfasd adsf.dsafadsf asd()dfasd
>   Dep.[dbo].jodnsf.sdfj afsdasf adfa.sda.asdf asfd () das INNER JOIN
>   [Dep].[dbo].ISIN_CALCULATED ISIN_FACT ON
>   (Dep.[dbo].ISIN.ISIN_ID=[Dep_LS].[dbo].EVENT.EVENT_ISSUER) INNER
>   [Dep_LS].dbo.ISINsdjndfadsfasd adsf.dsafadsf asd()dfasd
>   Dep_LS.dbo.jodnsf.sdfj afsdasf adfa.sda.asdf asfd () das INNER JOIN
>   Dep_LS.dbo.ISIN_CALCULATED ISIN_FACT ON
>   (Dep_LS.dbo.ISIN.ISIN_ID=Dep_LS.dbo.EVENT.EVENT_ISSUER) INNER
>   Dep.[dbo].ISINsdjndfadsfasd adsf.dsafadsf asd()dfasd
>   Dep_LS.[dbo].jodnsf.sdfj afsdasf adfa.sda.asdf asfd () das INNER JOIN
>   Dep_LS.[dbo].ISIN_CALCULATED ISIN_FACT ON
>   (Dep_LS.[dbo].ISIN.ISIN_ID=Dep_LS.[dbo].EVENT.EVENT_ISSUER)

finished result should be

```
<DEP>.dbo.ISINsdjndfadsfasd adsf.dsafadsf asd()dfasd
<DEP>.dbo.jodnsf.sdfj afsdasf adfa.sda.asdf asfd () das INNER JOIN
<DEP>.dbo.ISIN_CALCULATED ISIN_FACT ON
(<DEP>.dbo.ISIN.ISIN_ID=[Dep].dbo.EVENT.EVENT_ISSUER) INNER
<DEP>.[dbo].ISINsdjndfadsfasd adsf.dsafadsf asd()dfasd
<DEP>.[dbo].jodnsf.sdfj afsdasf adfa.sda.asdf asfd () das INNER JOIN
[Depend].[dbo].ISIN_CALCULATED ISIN_FACT ON
(<DEP>.[dbo].ISIN.ISIN_ID=[Dep_LS].[dbo].EVENT.EVENT_ISSUER) INNER
[Depend_LS].dbo.ISINsdjndfadsfasd adsf.dsafadsf asd()dfasd
<DEP>.dbo.jodnsf.sdfj afsdasf adfa.sda.asdf asfd () das INNER JOIN
<DEP>.dbo.ISIN_CALCULATED ISIN_FACT ON
(<DEP>.dbo.ISIN.ISIN_ID=Dep_LS.dbo.EVENT.EVENT_ISSUER) INNER
<DEP>.[dbo].ISINsdjndfadsfasd adsf.dsafadsf asd()dfasd
<DEP>.[dbo].jodnsf.sdfj afsdasf adfa.sda.asdf asfd () das INNER JOIN
<DEP>.[dbo].ISIN_CALCULATED ISIN_FACT ON
(<DEP>.[dbo].ISIN.ISIN_ID=Dep_LS.[dbo].EVENT.EVENT_ISSUER) Showing
14 matches Dep.dbo.ISINsdjndfadsfasd adsf.dsafadsf asd()dfasd
```

please bear in mind that this result is only from one paramaterString but there are 6 of them and each xml file should be checked by all 6 parameterStrings

Ok i got it working with regular expresion

> (Depend(?:_LS)?|[Depend(?:_LS)?])(.dbo|.[dbo)

so now code inside *while* loop looks like

`if (matcherDep.group(1) != null) { String replaceAll = 
      matcherDep.replaceAll("<DEP>$2>");
 }`

Comment: You got confused with groups in your pattern. Besides, you are using `matches()` as if it were `equals`. Please show an example string, explain what you need to get in the end.

Comment: updated, still using **matches()** as **equals()** should not interfier with **replaceAll()**.     Also using **equals()** gives same error.

Comment: In regex or general "*matching questions*" please always clearly state the input and the expected output. Best would be multiple inputs and the expected output. Useful tools for debugging regex are sites like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/). They show and explain you the exact structure of your regex and also show results for inputs.

Comment: i used regex.com and https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output     problem is it works without **replaceAll()** and for some time with it and then fails.

Comment: If you only need to wrap `DEP` or `DEP_LS` with `<` and `>`, why use such a complicated regex? Use a single regex directly to replace the strings: `s = s.replaceAll("Dep(?:_LS)?", "<$0>");`.

Comment: because there are in total 12 different variable i need to find and change also there posittion can be right after ( or =   . also Dep can be like [Dep]

Comment: Please add to your question the description of what needs to be matched and where (the context). Also, if the `.` or `=` may be missing, there is no point adding them to the pattern. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gm9IWM/1). Feel free to share an updated regex fiddle with more testing data.

Comment: is it better now? sweet code you have but it doesn't include all variants, i updated and added code what looks like in XML file, please look at it.

Comment: Ok Wiktor Stribižew it worked tnx you. how i can mark that your saution worked?